# Cannot access files in specific folder

Tags: windows, apache, wampserver

I'm running WampServer2 on a Windows 7 box, and I can't seem to access assets from a specific folder. To be more specific, when I try to access the file in:

```
[application path]/app/plugins/my_plugin/assets/image.png
```

it gives me a 403 - Forbidden error.

This seems to be an issue for the specific folder, because if I try to load assets from

```
[application path]/assets/image.png
```

everything works normally

Here is what I get from the Apache error log:

```
[Fri Jan 13 22:29:13 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server 
configuration: C:/my_vhosts/infector.eu/app/plugins/demo_plugin/assets/styles.css, 
referer: http://local.infector.eu/demo_plugin
```

Here is my virtual host settings in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.infector.eu
    DocumentRoot "C:/my_vhosts/infector.eu" 

    <Directory "C:/my_vhosts/infector.eu">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can't seem to figure out what's different about this folder, and it bugs me... The same application works fine in the pc I use at work which is an IIS PHP installation.

Any ideas about how to fix the permissions?

**[EDIT]**

**After some checks I realised that the app folder was Read Only... I have no idea how a read-only folder causes apache to be unable to load resources but after I unchecked the read-only box I get 403 no more!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check folder permissions? It could be that the IIS installation doesn't respect folder permissions the same way Apache does.